# Create a curve to show where an object will be projected in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, curve

I have some code below which projects an object along a curve to a given position and it works perfectly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject platform;
    public Vector3 targetPos;
    public float speed = 10;
    public float arcHeight = 1;

    Vector3 startPos;

    GameObject line;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        startPos = transform.position;
        targetPos = platform.transform.position;
        targetPos.x -= 0.7f;
        targetPos.y += 1.5f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
       movePlayer();
    }


    void movePlayer()
    {
        // Compute the next position, with arc added in
        float x0 = startPos.x;
        float x1 = targetPos.x;
        float dist = x1 - x0;
        float nextX = Mathf.MoveTowards(transform.position.x, x1, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        float baseY = Mathf.Lerp(startPos.y, targetPos.y, (nextX - x0) / dist);
        float arc = arcHeight * (nextX - x0) * (nextX - x1) / (-0.25f * dist * dist);
        Vector3 nextPos = new Vector3(nextX, baseY + arc, transform.position.z);


        transform.position = nextPos;

        // Do something when we reach the target
        if (nextPos == targetPos) Arrived();
    }

    void Arrived()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}
```

I want to now be able to add a visible curve which will show the path of the object. I have seen some examples which use LineRenderer but I am unsure about how to incorporate this into my way of moving the object. Any help about how to do this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code to have a LineRenderer create a path. The idea is that you generate the coordinates of your object in advance, using an position as input for the next location. (so not depending only on your object's transform).

Be sure to set a `Material` in the inspector, otherwise you will just see a pink line. I hope this is kind of what you had in mind.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject platform;
    public Vector3 targetPos;
    public float speed = 10;
    public float arcHeight = 1;

    Vector3 startPos;

    GameObject line;

    /// <summary>
    /// Our linerenderer
    /// </summary>
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Line material.
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField]
    private Material lineMaterial;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        startPos = transform.position;
        targetPos = platform.transform.position;
        targetPos.x -= 0.7f;
        targetPos.y += 1.5f;

        // Add a linerenderer.
        lineRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();

        if (lineMaterial == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No LineMaterial specified!");
        }

        // If you do not want to use worldspace, set this to false:
        lineRenderer.useWorldSpace = true;

        // Set preferred texture mode for texture.
        lineRenderer.textureMode = LineTextureMode.RepeatPerSegment;

        // Shadows, or not?
        //lineRenderer.shadowCastingMode = UnityEngine.Rendering.ShadowCastingMode.Off;
        //lineRenderer.receiveShadows = false;

        // Finally, set the material that you want to assign.
        // Remember: If you use default shader, it needs to be set to "Transparent" to get your texture's alpha working.
        lineRenderer.sharedMaterial = lineMaterial;


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        movePlayer();
    }

    private void movePlayer()
    {
        // Compute the next position, with arc added in
        Vector3 nextPos = newPosition(transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position = nextPos;

        // Calculate upcoming positions.
        Vector3[] points = generateUpcomingPositions(nextPos);
        CreateLine(points);


        // Do something when we reach the target
        if (nextPos == targetPos) Arrived();
    }

    private Vector3 newPosition(Vector3 currentPosition, float delta)
    {
        float x0 = startPos.x;
        float x1 = targetPos.x;
        float dist = x1 - x0;
        float nextX = Mathf.MoveTowards(currentPosition.x, x1, delta);
        float baseY = Mathf.Lerp(startPos.y, targetPos.y, (nextX - x0) / dist);
        float arc = arcHeight * (nextX - x0) * (nextX - x1) / (-0.25f * dist * dist);
        Vector3 nextPos = new Vector3(nextX, baseY + arc, currentPosition.z);

        return nextPos;
    }

    private Vector3[] generateUpcomingPositions(Vector3 currentPosition)
    {
        int steps = 10;
        float delta = (1.0f / ((steps - 1))) * 2.0f;// Double delta.
        List<Vector3> points = new List<Vector3>();

        Vector3 newPos = currentPosition;
        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
        {
            // Use newPos as input for location.
            newPos = newPosition(newPos, delta * i);

            points.Add(newPos);
        }

        return points.ToArray();
    }


    private void Arrived()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a line with a given name, width and points.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="points"></param>
    private void CreateLine(Vector3[] points)
    {

        // Set the positions.
        lineRenderer.positionCount = points.Length;
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(points);

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. The curve is drawn but slightly to the right of the object. Do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: Might it be due to your targetPos offset that you add yourself? I just tested it with a cube going to a sphere and it looks perfectly centered without it.

```
targetPos.x -= 0.7f;
targetPos.y += 1.5f;
```

Comment: turns out it was an error on how my sprite was designed. One last thing. The curve is really pixelated and blurry.  Is there a way to smooth it out? ive tried increasing the steps but that did nothing

Comment: This is what I would do for a simple improvement: Use a particle image and use that with the material configured as "fade". I created a quick particle texture for you [link](https://www.persistentrealities.com/shared/so/particle.png). Turn on Alpha for this texture(!) Use that as the diffuse texture. Set the line renderer textureMode  to "stretch". Result is like this: [link](http://www.persistentrealities.com/shared/so/arc-example.png). Play around with "emission" and other particle textures (try Google images for example)

Comment: I have added that image you sent into my assets folder and have created a new material and set the rendering mode to fade. However I am unsure how to link the image to the material. There are many different settings to link the image

Comment: Left of  "Albedo" there is a small square, you can assign the texture there by clicking on it (or drag & dropping the image in that square). See for example this image: [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/Inspector-MaterialSimple.png)

Comment: This is my Inspector here: https://imgur.com/UUHeMlY It looks slightly different to yours

Comment: Looks correct. But did you set the "Alpha is transparent" checkmark in your texture? See [transparency](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/StandardShaderTransparencyMapRGBAlphaToggle.jpg)

Comment: these are my settings: https://imgur.com/5MtDJ3Z  There are two examples of when I changed the texture type. I have played around with them and have checked and unchecked "Alpha is Transparency" and it seems no matter what I do the curve stays exactly the same

Comment: Your texture settings should not be set to "Sprite" (don't think that is the reason though). I put my assets directory online for you to take a look. I made it accidentally in v2018, but should work in any version > 2017. So you can take a look: [assets.zip](https://www.persistentrealities.com/shared/so/mover-assets.zip)